# When does the system show flag review screen?

Tags: support, flagging, review-queue

Today I had an yellow ellipse with "11" in it in my top toolbar next to "review" link, which took me to a screen allowing reviewing flagged posts.

I only recall seeing that screen once or twice before, in all my time here.

**What are the rules and circumstances for showing it?** Minimum rep? Random "quality control" review? Only when there are no mods around to action those flags for a certain amount of time?

I have a hard time believing that every flag that happens is displayed that way to high rep users, since I would have surely seen many more of them before today.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools

Comment: @DavRob60 - The only relevant info there seems to be the "Can I see all flags?" section, but even given limitations there I'd have expected to have been notified about non-mod-only flags way more often than I have been. E.g. duplicate flags, etc...

Comment: Duplicate flags goes to the [close review queue](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close). Only the flags that don't fit a (relatively new) special review queue, like "Not an answer", goes to the flag review queue.

Comment: That's odd. I've been over the 10k threshold for a week or so and I had that thing pop up about dozen of times. I suppose it depends on your time zone compared to the time zones of the mods.

Comment: High rep problems!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bubble is shown to users with access to the flag queue (10k on graduated sites, 2k on betas) when the queue gets above a certain size, I'm not sure the precise number it takes, I believe ~5.

Comment: "when the queue gets above a certain size" - that should explain the infrequency. Thanks!